# Select list selection changing another select list

Tags: jquery, select

I have a master select list in a column header that I need to have change the select lists in the column below it.

Here is the master:

```
 <select class='names header-select flag_pass_ID nsp-select' name='g1_head_select_flag_pass_ID'  onchange='select_all_batch(1, 1, "flag_pass_ID");' >
                        <option selected='selected' value='' ></option>
                        <option value='3' >Flag</option>
                        <option value='4' >Pass</option>
</select>
```

Here is one that needs to be changed:

```
<td class='data-edit widget data-select nsp-select flag_pass_ID' id='2503_r2_c8'>
                    <select class='names flag_pass_ID data-select nsp-select'  name='2503_select_table_nsp_status__flag_pass_ID'  onchange='make_input_changed(1);' size=1 >
                        <option selected='selected' value='' ></option>
                        <option value='3' >Flag</option>
                        <option value='4' >Pass</option>
                </select>
</td>
```

Here is the function called.

```
    function select_all_batch(grid_NM, current_page_NM, colclass) {
      if ( (typeof input_changed[grid_NM] != 'undefined') && 
               (input_changed[grid_NM] == true) ) {
        alert("Please Save or Cancel your other changes first." );
        return false;
      } else {
        //make_input_changed(grid_NM);
        var selection = $('.header-select.' + colclass + ' option:selected').val();
        $('.flag_pass_ID option[value=selection]').each(function() {
             (this).attr("selected", "selected");
        });
         //$('.flag_pass_ID').each(function() {
         //      (this).val(selection);
         //});
        //$("." + colclass + " option[value=selection]").each(function() {
        //     (this).val(selection);
        //     (this).attr("selected", "selected");
         //});
       return false;
       }
    }
```

I have confirmed that the var selection is getting the value.

The problem is in setting the selected option in the select lists below.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
function select_all_batch (grid_NM, current_page_NM, colclass) {
    var selection = $('.header-select.' + colclass + ' option:selected').val();
    $('.flag_pass_ID select option[value=' + selection + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

This should work provided the values on the second select correspond with the first one, even if they don't have the same order.

http://jsfiddle.net/EBZG9/

Comment: That was it!  I understand the syntax with the value.  But not understanding why I did not need an each, as that should be returning the options of multiple selects.  I thought you always needed an each in that case.  Oh well.